# How to add attribute to class with js?

Tags: javascript, class, automation

So I am trying to autofill the discount code section on a page. The class I am calling is [button before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4f0s.png). If I try to press enter it isn't applying the code, because the value wasn't saved somehow. However, filling it out manually addes this attribute to the class: [after entering code manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHBLy.png). The site I am trying to apply discount on is luisaviaroma.com you can try the FF25 code, if you are interested in helping me with some code. I figured out that simply adding a space after the code my hand is solving the issue, is there a way to make this space press automated to (inside of js)?

```
function test() {
    var element = document.querySelector("div[data-attribute='promo-code-input']")
    var input = document.querySelector("input[name='promo-code-input']");
    //element.setAttribute('class', 'InputText__baseCls___Hg_ik4cV2- InputText__focus___5q7tEpbHwI InputText__filled___1s5BW_63Y3');
    element.classList.add("InputText__filled___1s5BW_63Y3");
    console.log(element)
    input.focus();
    setTimeout(function () {
        input.focus();
        input.value='FF25';
        let event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent('change', true, false);
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
        element.blur();
    }, 300)
    input.select();
```

Comment: edited the post

Comment: Where are you trying to add a space?

Comment: I am not, because I don't really know how to simulate a keypress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is a `KeyboardEvent` the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) recommends `input` for text inputs.

In this case setting the `bubbles` attribute to true does the trick.

```
function test(val) {
    var input = document.querySelector("input[name='promo-code-input']");
    var inputEvent = new Event('input', {
           bubbles: true,
         })

    input.focus();
    input.value = val;
    input.dispatchEvent(inputEvent)

    console.log(input)

 }
```

Comment: worked, you are my hero. Can you help me with one more thing? I want to press the payment button at the very end of the payment process. The button changes once you have picked a payment method. For now I am able to choose the payment method or click the disabled button. Somehow I can't click on the enabled payment button. 
function payNow() {
    document.querySelector("[class='Totals__totalsButton___2ToMDI87tI']").click();
    console.log("click pay")
}
this is the click function I am using. Probably I need to delay this part

Comment: prego! you just need to select the child element, as the selector is getting the parent div not the button: `document.querySelector("[class='Totals__totalsButton___2ToMDI87tI']").firstChild.click()`